# The connection name 'DefaultConnection' was not found in the applications configuration or the connection string is empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc, connection-string, azure-table-storage, account

I am using Azure Tables, so i don't know how my connection string should be?
can anyone please guide for the same.

I am using the Account Controller provided by MVC 3 Internet template as is. Then too i am getting the following error:

The connection name 'DefaultConnection' was not found in the applications configuration or the connection string is empty.

Answer (score 0):

The Azure portal should give you any connection string you need to utilize your datastore. I haven't used their simplistic "tables" datastore, so I'm not sure if it actually even has a connection string. You should refer to the Azure documentation to determine exactly how you utilize the tables in your application.

As for the error you're getting, the `AccountsModels.cs` file that the default MVC 4 internet application template generates contains a `DbContext` subclass inside that directly references the "DefaultConnection" connection string. If your connection string's name is different, change this reference to match. If you have no connection string, add one that matches the name in that file. If Azure's "tables" have no connection string, I'm not sure what you'll have to do to integrate with Entity Framework, but there's surely documentation on that somewhere online.